# ValueError while scraping instagram with python

Tags: python, web-scraping, instagram

Hello I am trying to scrape this url : `https://www.instagram.com/cristiano/?__a=1` but I get a Value Error

```
    url_user = "https://www.instagram.com/cristiano/?__a=1"
    headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/70.0.3538.77 Safari/537.36'}

    response = get(url_user,headers=headers)
    print(response) # 200
    html_soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser')
    # print(html_soup)
    jsondata=json.loads(str(html_soup))
```

`ValueError: No JSON object could be decoded`

Any idea why I get this error?

Comment: Not able to reproduce error.

Comment: why not just `json_data = response.json()`?

Comment: In addition to my previous comment - I also cannot reproduce the error. print `response.text` so that you see what you really get.

Answer (score 0):

The reason you're getting the error is because you're trying to parse a JSON response as if it was HTML. You don't need BeautifulSoup for that.

Try this:

```
import json
import requests

url_user = "https://www.instagram.com/cristiano/?__a=1"
d = json.loads(requests.get(url_user).text)
print(d)
```

However, best practice suggests to use `.json()` from `requests`, as it'll do a better job of figuring out the encoding used.

```
import requests

url_user = "https://www.instagram.com/cristiano/?__a=1"
d = requests.get(url_user).json()
print(d)
```

Comment: The second code gives me this error : simplejson.errors.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

Comment: @userHG there's no `json` module in the second snippet so I don't know why you would get the error.

Answer (score 0):

You might be getting non-200 [HTTP Status Code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes), which means that server responded with error, e.g. server might have banned your IP for frequent requests. `requests` library doesn't throw any errors for that. To control erroneous status codes insert after `get(...)` line this code:

```
response.raise_for_status()
```

Also it is enough just to do `jsondata = response.json()`. `requests` library can parse json this way without need for beautiful soup. Easy to read tutorial about main requests library features is [located here](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/user/quickstart/).

Also if there is some parsing problem save binary content of response to file to attach it to question like this:

```
with open('response.dat', 'wb') as f:
    f.write(response.content)
```